# Swapping between two nodes using the given elements which are present in these nodes. Python-3.0 is used for writing code

Tags: python, data-structures, swap, singly-linked-list

I have written code but I think push function is not working as when I am calling display function no element is showing in the linked list. Please tell me how to append elements in linked list and explain steps. I think last_pointer is considered as local variable and it is not storing last value of it. If every time I declare last_pointer then it will not add to the next node.

Output is:

```
Linked list before any swapping
key1 is not present in the list
key1 is not present in the list
key1 is not present in the list
____________________
```

---

```
# Swapping between two nodes present in linkedlist

class node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None
class linkedlist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
    def push(self,newdata):
        newnode=node(newdata)
        if(self.head==None):
            last_pointer=self.head
            last_pointer=newnode
            last_pointer=last_pointer.next
        else:
            last_pointer.next=newnode
            last_pointer=last_pointer.next
    def swapnodes(self,key1,key2):
        node1=self.head
        node2=self.head
        #if elements are similar
        if(key1==key2):
            print("keys are similar")
            return
        #find previous of element and element location in the list
        while(node1):
            if(node1==key1):
                break
            prevofnode1=node1
            node1=node1.next
        while(node2):
            if(node2==key2):
                break
            prevofnode2=node2
            node2=node2.next
        #if elements are not present in the list
        if(node1==None):
            print("key1 is not present in the list")
            return
        if(node2==None):
            print("key2 is not present in the list")
            return
        #if node present at beginning or at mid or at end
        temp1=node2.next
        temp2=node1.next
        if(prevofnode1==None):
            self.head=node2
            node2.next=node1.next
            prevofnode2=node1
            node1.next=temp1
            temp1=None
        else:
            prevofnode1=node2
            node2.next=node1.next
            prevofnode2=node1
            node1.next=temp1
            temp1=None
        if(prevofnode2==None):
            self.head=node1
            node1.next=node2.next
            prevofnode1=node2
            node2.next=temp2
            temp2=None
        else:
            prevofnode2=node1
            node1.next=node2.next
            prevofnode1=node2
            node2.next=temp2
            temp2=None
    def display(self):
        temp=self.head
        while(temp):
            print(temp.data)
            temp=temp.next
llist=linkedlist()
llist.push(22)
llist.push(92)
llist.push(-20)
llist.push(2)
llist.push(23)
llist.push(102)
print("Linked list before any swapping")
llist.display()
llist.swapnodes(22,102)
llist.swapnodes(22,-20)
llist.swapnodes(22,13)
llist.display()
```

Comment: Please, post the error messages as well.

Comment: please check now. Thanks